# Можно ли начать воспроизведение тега audio не с начала а с конкретной секунды?

Tags: javascript, jquery, аудио

Доброго времени! Такой вопрос - можно ли средствами javascript сделать так что бы аудиофайл на сайте начал воспроизводиться не с начала, а допустим с заданной секунды? К примеру при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: можно - currentTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var pl = document.getElementById('player');
pl.currentTime = 30.0;
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="http://files.realmusic.ru/download/1577511/id195399_-_bi-2_feat._Oxxxymiron_-_pora_vozvraschatsya_domoi_(lyric_video).mp3" controls></audio>
```